# How do I print out the full traceback in my except call?

Tags: python

Right now, I do this:

```
try:
    blah
except Exception, e:
    print e
    time.sleep(9999)
```

Instead of print e, I want to print out the entire traceback.  And then sleep it for 999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import traceback  
traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Do I put that inside my except?

Comment: @TIMEX: You could try reading about the `traceback` module before asking.  Then, after reading, you could ask a more specific question that makes sense.